# Angular 2+ - Child modules not displaying in Chrome Extension

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a very simple two-page extension: the first page handles login and the second is a button for checking in. The purpose of the extension is to save users the trouble of having to go to the website if all they want to do is just check-in.

The problem I'm encountering now is that everything seems to be working fine on localhost:4200 but when I load the project and open it as an extension it just displays a blank square.

I'm guessing this happens because my `"default_popup"` opens `src/index.html` which doesn't contain anything in its `<body>` other than `<app-root></app-root>`. But in localhost it's all working fine...

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/proofoflife/chrome-extension/overview) is my project so far, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**[EDIT]** Since no one is replying let me make my question a lot simpler:
Can I use Angular 4 to write a Chrome extension? What are the limitations? Can anyone explain me or point me to any documentation that teaches how to implement it?

Comment: Since no one is replying let me make my question a lot simpler:
Can I use Angular 4 to write a Chrome extension? What are the limitations? Can anyone explain me or point me to any documentation that teaches how to implement it?

Comment: You sure can, I created an extension in Angular 4. I'm not sure if you can use Angular in your background scripts (or if there's any point), but on the front size there are no limitations that I know of.
Based on what you said this should be a configuration issue, most likely in your manifest.json or angular-cli.json. I don't see a build script so I'm not sure how you build your app, but for example are you sure that the default_popup should be src/index.html and not just index.html?

Comment: @barney.balazs I have tried copying the index.html to the parent folder, assigning default_popup to src/app/app.component.html instead. Still, localhost displays the project but the extension just displays a blank square. I will add the dist folder to the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! finally I found a decent [article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/software-tools/developing-google-chrome-extension-using-angular-4/). Apparently the problem was that all I needed to upload was the `dist` folder (that is created automatically after a successfull build) instead of the parent folder. This only works if the `manifest.json` is included inside the `assets` in the `angular-cli.json` file. In this way you have to re-build the project every time that you update the extension but at least now routing can be used.

Problem solved, everything is working perfectly now, please close this.